# Using an array as a hashmap key

Tags: java

I am trying to use an Array as the keys in a HashMap. The arrays are of length two, so are essentially acting as a 2-tuple. Implementing a custom 2-tuple class is a very last resort. The problem is, I want arrays with the same contents map to different location in the HashMap if they have different memory locations. I know there are hashCode functions in Arrays.hashCode and Arrays.deepHashCode, but is there any way I can use these for a HashMap. As I already said, I really don't want to implement my own tuple class.

Comment: I ran into roughly the same problem some time ago and gave up.  I don't think you can change the hashing behavior of a primitive array. Granting that, you have a brilliant case for introducing a new `SerializableTuple` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Instead of using an array, I used List instead. This works because List determines equality by contents, and not by reference.

Answer (score 3):

I would *not* recommend this approach.

Keys must be immutable.  Unless you make your array so it'll be fraught with peril.

Java's an object-oriented language.  I think it's a mistake to think too much in terms of primitives.  Encapsulate the proper behavior that you need in objects.

Why is creating your own class so oppressive?  Last resort?  I don't understand why this is such a big deal.  Create it, make it immutable, document your intention clearly, and move on.

Update: I would not let the fact that you already have a flawed tuple class prevent you from doing the right thing in this case.  You say you have "hundreds of classes" - I say that doing the right thing with one more will not break you.  Code ends up in a shambles through the accumulation of "practical", bad decisions like the one you're about to make.  Resolve to not add to the cruft by creating the right solution for this narrow problem and start working your way out from there to a better answer.

Comment: We already have a tuple implementation, but it cannot be serialized by our serializer, and I need this information to be serialized. I am not going to duplicate functionality, and our tuple implementation is one of the main data structures of our project, which spans hundreds of classes.

Comment: The right solution here is to suck it up and write the new `Pair` class, or even better, to write a class with a more specific name and specific field names.  Arrays should never be used when different elements have different meanings.  Even if there were some way to use `Arrays.equals` or `Arrays.hashCode` here -- which there isn't -- writing a new class would be the unambiguously right solution here.

Comment: @Max - the simple solution is to change your existing (immutable) tuple type to make it serializable.  What it the risk?  Making your tuple class serializable can't break existing code that doesn't try to serialize tuples ...

Comment: @StephenC We don't actually write the serialization methods ourselves. We rely on libraries using reflection. Our tuple contains a reference to itself, I believe, which is why it cannot be serialized. I have no idea how and where this reference is used, and I would prefer not to waste a day or two finding out.

Comment: A reference to itself?  You mean "this"?  I'm glad I'm not working on that system.   Good luck.

Comment: @Max - the primary reason that cruft builds up in system is because of decisions like the one you are making ...

Comment: @duffymo I have no idea where the self-reference is. It could be that the tuple contains some other object, and that other object stores a reference to the tuple. This is known as strong coupling and it is not a recommended practice. We are using some code written by researchers, and research code is usually terrible. It is too late, because this stuff cannot be changed.

Comment: Researchers I know are smart enough to write good code.  Maybe your sample size is too small.  "Cannot be changed"?  Never.  Make the case or accept your fate.  Start writing JUnit tests and refactor slowly as you go.  It's your only hope.  Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure they actually write good code? It's not a question of intelligence, it is just a matter of use. Researchers don't spend years maintaining code, so there isn't a compelling reasons to write maintainable code. For instance, I doubt many researchers have a code review process. I use two large libraries from Stanford and they are both poorly written from a maintainability standpoint. And we have extensive tests, with 100% code coverage and around 80% branch coverage, but no one is going to approve such a widespread change. Thanks for your help I guess.

Comment: I didn't say all researchers; I said I can think of instances where very good code has been written by people who aren't professional programmers.  You just don't work for them.  Researchers often become involved with code over a long period of time.  No need for me to argue - you're screwed.  Good luck.  I have no idea why you came here to ask a question if all you were going to do is tell people why their answers were worthless.

Comment: I don't know why you answered with a solution I specifically stated I could not use.

Comment: You edited that bit in, if I recall correctly.  Your original wording had no such stipulation.  Besides, I'd rather tell you the truth.  As you can see, there hasn't been another answer forthcoming.  We'll see if a better one shows up.

Comment: I actually found a solution. I just used List<Integer> instead of an array. Also, you can check the revision history, that requirement was there from the beginning.

Comment: Make it an immutable List or you'll have problems.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, I want arrays with the same contents map to different location in the HashMap if they have different memory locations.

If the *arrays* have different memory locations, or if the *contents* of the arrays have different memory locations? If it's the former, you can probably use an [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) instead of a normal `HashMap`. If it's the latter, however, then I strongly agree with @duffymo's answer: [grow a pair](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/05/anatomy-of-annoyance.html) ;)